# Save image from PHP URL - returns empty image

Tags: php, html, image, curl

I'm working on a small project where I read data from electronic identity cards.

It might be worth mentioning I'm using the LightOpenID PHP library to get `$attributes['']` with all the data from the eID.

Now I'm **stuck trying to save an image** which is displayed on `http://my-url.com/photo.php`

*photo.php contains:*

```
<?php
session_start();

$photo = $_SESSION['photo'];

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

echo($photo);
```

The variable `$photo` contains `$_SESSION['photo']` which comes from *index.php*:

```
function base64url_decode($base64url) {
    $base64 = strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/');
    $plainText = base64_decode($base64);
    return ($plainText);
}

$encodedPhoto = $attributes['eid/photo'];
$photo = base64url_decode($encodedPhoto);
$_SESSION['photo'] = $photo;
```

The images are both perfectly visible on index.php (`<?php echo '<img src="photo.php"/>'; ?>`) as well as on photo.php.

I've read up on a few similar topics and tried the following methods:

1. **cURL**

> ```
> $ch = curl_init();    
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://my-url.com/photo.php');     
> $fp = fopen('./photo/' . $filename . '.jpg', 'wb');      
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);      
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);      
> curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);      
> fclose($fp);
> ```

2. **File_put_contents**

> ```
>  $input = "my-url.com/photo.php";
>  $output = './photo/' . $filename . '.jpg';
>  file_put_contents($output, file_get_contents($input));
> ```

1. **copy**

Even tried a basic copy:

```
copy( "http://my-url/photo.php", './photo/' . $filename . '.jpg');
```

All 3 methods create an **empty .jpg** file in the directory I want them too.

Let me know if I need to provide any extra code.
Hope there's someone who can point out my mistakes

Comment: I'm not sure, but to do this wouldn't you need to set the session cookie in curl so it would know how to set the session and get the image?

Comment: what does `$filename` should actually contain ? you use it but I don't see any place where it's defined... and have you try and force header ?

Comment: Was this on the same webserver? Did you have a reason to do this by curling the server, why not just pull the image out of the session again?

Comment: $filename contains a series of numbers provided from an identity. The image gets a name like ex.: 93062339141.jpg.
I'll try both to set cookies and to force a header. I'll keep this updated.

Comment: You can pass the filename with the url. For example use the url: http://my-url.com/photo.php?filename=your-file-name. Then you will have to update photo.php so it checks if the filename is given in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

I decode the base64url only once with:

```
function base64url_decodeOnce($base64url){
    $base64 = strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/');
    return ($base64);
}
```

that way I can use the $base64 output for:

```
$data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $base64data .'\'';
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('./photo/' . $filename . '.jpg', $data);
```